# Joomla 3 PHP errors when uploading files through the media manager

Tags: php, joomla, foreach

Whenever I try to upload files I get a blank white screen with the following PHP error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 64

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 72

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 109
```

Comment: What is your setup? Specifically, server and PHP version.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.27
CGI/FastCGI

Comment: Are you sure that these files are not corrupted? Maybe you should download a clean Joomla and compare those files. Even better if you could install another Joomla site in your server and see if the media manager is working.